# I have many queries and I want to do them in 1 step

Tags: sql, ms-access

If someone can help me that would be appreciated.

I have let's say:
A) 500 rows of data

1. I do a LEFT JOIN and find matching 100 rows by Item. I put that in Table 1
2. I do another LEFT JOIN to find out the rest of the 400 rows of data and I put that in Table 2
3. I do another LEFT JOIN to find out on Table 2 to find out matching 200 rows of data by UPC. I put that in Table 3
4. Then I do a UNION to join Table 1 and Table 3

As you can see I am doing 4 steps. How can i do it in 1 step. I know Sub-query but when i do it in access it says "Sub-query doesn't support.

This is my actual code and it works:

1) This helps me find the items that are matching in my 2 files.

```
SELECT [STEP 1: SYSCO_CITY_UPDATE].*, [MAT_INFO_NHS_UNIQUE_UPC].[Category Description] 
INTO [STEP 2: SYSCO_ITEM_CAPTURED]
FROM [STEP 1: SYSCO_CITY_UPDATE] 
LEFT JOIN MAT_INFO_NHS_UNIQUE_UPC 
ON [STEP 1: SYSCO_CITY_UPDATE].[MANUF PROD CODE] = VAL([MAT_INFO_NHS_UNIQUE_UPC].[Material]);
```

2) This helps me find out the **REST** of the data that wasn't matched:

```
SELECT [STEP 2: SYSCO_ITEM_CAPTURED].* INTO [STEP 3: SYSCO_REST]
FROM [STEP 2: SYSCO_ITEM_CAPTURED]
WHERE [STEP 2: SYSCO_ITEM_CAPTURED].[CATEGORY DESCRIPTION] IS NULL;
```

3) This helps me find out UPC that are matching from the Rest of the data:

```
SELECT [STEP 3: SYSCO_REST].*, [MAT_INFO_NHS_UNIQUE_UPC].[Category Description] 
INTO [STEP 4: SYSCO_UPC_CAPTURED]
FROM [STEP 3: SYSCO_REST] 
LEFT JOIN MAT_INFO_NHS_UNIQUE_UPC 
ON [STEP 3: SYSCO_REST].[SCC] = VAL([MAT_INFO_NHS_UNIQUE_UPC].[SCC for Case or Pallet]);
```

Then I do a UNION on Table 1 and Table 3

Thanks if anyone can help.

Sam

Comment: Why is it necessary to save records to other tables?

Comment: So Table1 is [STEP 2: SYSCO_ITEM_CAPTURED] and Table3 is [STEP 4: SYSCO_UPC_CAPTURED]?

Answer (score 1):

It can get ugly but nesting queries should be possible.

Query 1

```
SELECT [STEP 1: SYSCO_CITY_UPDATE].*, [MAT_INFO_NHS_UNIQUE_UPC].[Category Description] 
FROM [STEP 1: SYSCO_CITY_UPDATE] 
LEFT JOIN MAT_INFO_NHS_UNIQUE_UPC 
ON [STEP 1: SYSCO_CITY_UPDATE].[MANUF PROD CODE] = VAL([MAT_INFO_NHS_UNIQUE_UPC].[Material])
```

Query2

```
SELECT [STEP 3: SYSCO_REST].*, [MAT_INFO_NHS_UNIQUE_UPC].[Category Description] 
FROM (SELECT [STEP 2: SYSCO_ITEM_CAPTURED].*
      FROM (SELECT [STEP 1: SYSCO_CITY_UPDATE].*, [MAT_INFO_NHS_UNIQUE_UPC].[Category Description] 
            FROM [STEP 1: SYSCO_CITY_UPDATE] 
            LEFT JOIN MAT_INFO_NHS_UNIQUE_UPC 
            ON [STEP 1: SYSCO_CITY_UPDATE].[MANUF PROD CODE] = VAL([MAT_INFO_NHS_UNIQUE_UPC].[Material])) AS [STEP 2: SYSCO_ITEM_CAPTURED]
      WHERE [STEP 2: SYSCO_ITEM_CAPTURED].[CATEGORY DESCRIPTION] IS NULL) AS  [STEP 3: SYSCO_REST] 
LEFT JOIN MAT_INFO_NHS_UNIQUE_UPC 
ON [STEP 3: SYSCO_REST].[SCC] = VAL([MAT_INFO_NHS_UNIQUE_UPC].[SCC for Case or Pallet]);
```

Now build a UNION query from Query1 and Query2. The UNION could also use nesting but I don't know the fields needed in the UNION so cannot show that structure. If the * field wildcard pulled in the same fields in same order in each SELECT, then just UNION the two statements. Keep in mind the first SELECT defines field names and data types.

Saving into 'temp' tables can be justified if it speeds up processing. However, saving into multiple tables cannot be done in 1 SQL statement. Build VBA procedure to sequentially run SQL actions.

Answer (score 0):

Since MS-Access does not support CTEs, maybe you can use plain Table Expressions. Try and see if it works:

```
select -- your third query here
from (
  select ... -- your first query
) step1,
(
  select ... -- your second query
) step2
```

Comment: Question is regarding SQL usage within Access database. Are CTEs still relevant?

Comment: You are absolutely right. I didn't see the ms-access tag. Maybe the modified solution could work, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Looks like MS-Access doesn't support plain table expression either.